# Large LED Matrix Display of 10 lines of 12 rows x 128 columns

Tags: led, led-matrix

I need help to drive 10 LED matrix display each of 12 rows x 128 columns.
I am unable to find LED driver that can drive 12 x 128 LED matrix display.

My project requirements are:
1. All 10 LED matrix display has Monochrome LEDs

Is it possible to use daisy chain technique to tie up multiple drivers ? How ? If not possible, what could be the alternative ?
How to supply power this huge LED display matrix ?
Also suggest me the driver chip suitable for my requirement.

Comment: Can all 15,360 LEDs be activated simultaneously? What power per LED? What LED? What drivers have you so far located? What background work have you done and what application?

Comment: You could go full RGB and use WS2812 LEDs with integrated controllers.

Answer (score 1):

You won't find a chip that can drive 128 LEDs but there are a few that can drive 16 columns: -

[image]

There is another TI chip that can do 24 channels of LEDs - the TL5947 and there's also a 32 channel chip from linear tech called the LT3746 - it has integrated power management to suit multiple leds in series and varying supply voltages.

Answer (score 0):

You may use multiple shift registers in your case (example : 74HC595 )
this example will help you to get an idea 
http://arduino.cc/en/tutorial/ShiftOut#.Uy-xyaaHH5A